# Adding a file as attachment

Tags: swift, uiview, swift3

I am trying to find out how to make a user pick a file (pdf, doc...) as an attachment.

I've done it with an image, but now I am struggling to do it with any file.
using an image I did it like this:

```
let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary 
    image.allowsEditing = false        
    self.present(image, animated: true)
    {


   }
```

Can anyone give me some hints or clues how to do it for generic files? thanks

EDIT: The idea is so that the user could press a button and than an epxlorer would open so that the user can choose a file from his iphone (later the file would be to store with coredata).

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What do you mean by "pick a file as an attachment"? An attachment to what? Where is the file to be chosen from? Please update your question with these clarifications. Do not post comments.

Comment: I've put some code of a simillar thing I've done to Image, so I thought it was clear enough. I've edit the question. If you have any doubt please feel free to comment.

Comment: You can't just pick files from your iOS device. An app is sandboxed. What files are you referring to specifically?

Comment: Let's say I have a pdf in my device. And I want to pick it and store it with core data.... Look at the code I've posted to Images. I want to do the same thing but for generic files

Comment: Where is the PDF stored? Is it from your own app's sandbox or from another app? There is no central repository of files in iOS like images.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no file manager in iOS? Or that I cannot copy a pdf into a directory of the phone and latter access it and open it. With that file manager.

Comment: Do you see a file manager in iOS? Your app can store files in its own sandbox and you can give the user some UI to select one of those files, but there is no file manager to some central file repository.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129295/discussion-between-h-n-and-rmaddy).